# select max value from a string column in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, max

I have table with a column `Order` of type `varchar` as follows

```
Order
-----
Ord-998,
Ord-999,
Ord-1000,
Ord-1001,
```

I want to get the max value as 1001

But when I run this query, I am getting 999 as max value always

```
select 
    SUBSTRING((select isnull(MAX(OrderNo), '0000000') 
               from OrderSummary 
               where OrderNo like 'Ord%'), 5, 10) as [OrderMax]
```

Can anybody provide a solution?

Comment: Life will be so much easier if you have a separate column to store the unique integer values.

Comment: Sorting is a funky thing. Lots of variables (collation, time zone, data type, etc.). Since you are trying to sort by strings, it has different rules than sorting by integers.

Comment: I am scared as to why you want the max value. Are you trying to do something horrible like MAX(OrderNum) + 1 before you insert a new one? I would get rid of the silly "Ord-" prefix as it does nothing but make things more difficult.

Comment: Yes i want to get max value +1

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since you are maxing a string it is sorting alphabetically where C is larger than AAA and 9 is larger than 10. Remove the letters and cast it as an int then get the max. Given that it will always be Ord-### we can remove the Ord- and cast the remainder as an INT.

```
SELECT
    MAX(CAST(SUBSTRING(OrderNo,5,LEN(OrderNo)-4) AS INT))
FROM OrderSummary
WHERE OrderNo LIKE 'Ord-%'
```

Comment: Thanks brother. you saved my time

Comment: Very nice answer, I have upvoted it. If you are interested in an alternative, you can check my answer too.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility would be the `REPLACE`-function:

```
SELECT
    MAX(CONVERT(int,(REPLACE(OrderNo, 'Ord-' ,'')))) AS OrderMax
FROM OrderSummary;
```

But like already mentioned in comments, the best solution will be to get rid of the "Ord-" and create a `int`-column instead.

Answer (score 0):

If I were tackling this issue I would Order Number as an integer instead of a varchar, and not store the repetitive text "Ord-" in the field.  If end users require "Ord-998", I'd handle it via my CRUD layer.

This also allows you to declare the Order Number column as an identity column, which will handle the automatic incrementing for you.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this query in SQL Server

```
select MAX(convert(int, substring(orderno, 5, LEN(orderno)))) 
from OrderSummary
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem, as stated in other answers is that you have a string. I will provide here an alternative solution: you could `select top 1` from your table and have an `order by len(OrderNo) desc, OrderNo desc`. This way you will not have to cut all the `varchar`s and convert them to integer, but will be able to simply compare their length (very quick) and if similar, their `varchar` value (pretty slow). Of course, a default for null values is a good idea, but make sure you do not put more 0-s there than the number of digits of your first number.

Answer (score 0):

I attach another possible solution this query is posgresQL

```
SELECT
CONCAT(RPAD('Ord-',5), MAX(CAST(SUBSTRING(OrderNo,5,length(OrderNo)-4) AS INT)))AS 
ORDER
FROM  OrderSummary
```

RESULT

Order
Ord-1001

Answer (score 0):

Use `len` keyword instead of `like` keyword

```
select MAX(CAST(SUBSTRING(OrderNo, 6, len(OrderNo)) AS INT)) FROM OrderSummary
```

Answer (score 0):

u can cast as int,it will consider value,not lexic. order
ie.
max(cast(Col as int)) from `Table`